# Find all cells with "number"."number" in a list and copy the entire row to a different location

Tags: excel, vba, search

thank you in advance for even looking at this ;)
So i am trying to find several words in a list all good but now I'm trying to find possible dates and just doesn't work. I tried everything I could think off.. I'm out of ideias.

This is the part of the code I'm trying to work with.

```
Option Compare Text

Sub Test()
Dim CL As Range

Dim POS As Long

For Each CL In Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(4).Cells
    POS = 0

    If InStr(1, CL.text, "test") > 0 Then POS = InStr(1, CL.text, "test")

    If InStr(1, CL.text, "example") > 0 Then POS = InStr(1, CL.text, "example")

     If InStr(1, CL.text, "[0-9].[0-9]") > 0 Then POS = InStr(1, CL.text, "[0-9].[0-9]")

    'i know the last IF is not ok ,but dont want to share my stupid rookie mistakes :)

    'its just to give the idea of what im looking for.

        If POS > 0 Then

    With CL.Characters.Font

      .FontStyle = "bold"

      .Color = -16383844

    End With

With CL.Interior

    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic

    .Color = 13551615

    End With

      With CL.Select

      a = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

                Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion).Copy

          Worksheets("data").Cells(a + 1, 8).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    End With  

End If

Next CL

End Sub
```

Once again thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe , if these are actual numbers you can minimize the cells to loop through with Specialcells. Also, you might want to look into Like operator if you plan on using character classes.

Comment: Hi JvdV, thanks for your answer. The purpose is to detect the "." When surrounded by numbers. Like I said I'm quite a noob. Can you give me a simple example and il try to go from there?

Comment: Tried with like. It does work. But the problem is that sometimes there is also text. And doesn't seem to like it when there is text.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `Like` operator rather than `InStr()` for this one test:

```
Sub dural()
    s = "kjhgf56yh8.9sdfgtyjn"
    MsgBox s Like "*#.#*"
End Sub
```

So in your code:

```
If CL.Text Like "*#.#*" Then POS = 1
```

This is a cheat.  You can get away with it because do don't need the actual value of `POS`, only the fact that it is greater than zero.

Comment: You are THA MAN. I can sleep now. Thank you guys.